# Spring Boot with AsyncRestTemplate Netty Client Fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netty, kotlin

I have a Spring Boot 1.3.6 application, built out of the box and using the embedded Tomcat server. The application has a single endpoint doing a very simple echo request.

Later I defined a corresponding client invoking that simple endpoint using `AsyncRestTemplate`, however if my client uses the `Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory` the request fails, otherwise it succeeds.

My example below is in Kotlin, but it fails just the same in Java, so it does not have to do with the language I use to implement it.

#### The Server

```
@SpringBootApplication
open class EchoApplication {

    companion object {
       @JvmStatic fun main(args: Array<String>) {
          SpringApplication.run(EchoApplication::class.java, *args)
       }
    }

    @Bean
    open fun objectMapper(): ObjectMapper {
        return ObjectMapper().apply {
            dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")
            registerModule(KotlinModule())
        }
    }

    @Bean
    open fun customConverters(): HttpMessageConverters {
        return HttpMessageConverters(listOf(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper())))
    }
}
```

My endpoint looks like this:

```
@RestController
class EchoController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/foo", method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.PUT))
    fun echo(@RequestBody order: Order): Order {
        return order
    }

}
```

And the order data class is

```
data class Order(val orderId: String)
```

Note: Since I use Kotlin, I also added the [Kotlin Jackson Module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin) to ensure proper constructor deserialization.

#### The Client

I then proceeded to create a client that invokes this endpoint.

If I do something like the following in my client, it works perfectly and I get a successful echo response.

```
    val executor = TaskExecutorAdapter(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2))
    val restTemplate = AsyncRestTemplate(executor)
    restTemplate.messageConverters = listOf(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper))

    val promise = restTemplate.exchange(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/foo"), HttpMethod.PUT, HttpEntity(Order("b1254"), headers), Order::class.java)
    promise.addCallback(object : ListenableFutureCallback<ResponseEntity<Order>> {
        override fun onSuccess(result: ResponseEntity<Order>) {
            println(result.body)
        }

        override fun onFailure(ex: Throwable) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
            if(ex is HttpStatusCodeException){
                println(ex.responseBodyAsString)
            }
        }
    })
```

As mentioned above, the code above runs perfectly and prints a successful echo response.

#### The Problem

But if I decide to use the Netty client, then I get 400 Bad Request reporting I did not pass the body:

```
val nettyFactory = Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory()
val restTemplate = AsyncRestTemplate(nettyFactory)
```

When I do this then I get a `HttpMessageNotReadableException` with a message saying "Required request body is missing".

I debugged the Spring Boot code and I see that when the `ServletInputStream` is read, it always return -1 as if it was empty.

In my gradle I added `runtime('io.netty:netty-all:4.1.2.Final')`, so I am using what, as of today, is the latest version of Netty. This Netty version has worked just fine when interacting with endpoints in other projects that I have that use regular Spring (i.e. not Spring Boot).

How come the `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` works fine, but the `Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory` fails?

I thought it might had to do with the embedded Tomcat server, however, if I package this application as war and deploy it in an existing Tomcat server (i.e. not using the embedded one), the problem persists. So, I'm guessing is something related to Spring/Spring Boot.

Am I missing any configuration in my Spring Boot app? Any suggestions on how to make the Netty client work with Spring Boot?

Comment: did u figure out why MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter is not parsing the json? im seeing the same error in java. if you look at the documentation for asyncresttemplate "The AsyncRestTemplate exposes a synchronous RestTemplate via the getRestOperations() method and shares its error handler and message converters with that RestTemplate."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there are problem in serialization on Client's side. Because this code works perfect:

```
restTemplate.exchange(
        URI.create("http://localhost:8080/foo"),
        HttpMethod.PUT,
        HttpEntity("""{"orderId":"1234"}""", HttpHeaders().apply {
            setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        }),
        Order::class.java
).addCallback(object : ListenableFutureCallback<ResponseEntity<Order>> {
    override fun onSuccess(result: ResponseEntity<Order>) {
        println("Result: ${result.body}")
    }

    override fun onFailure(ex: Throwable) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
        if (ex is HttpStatusCodeException) {
            println(ex.responseBodyAsString)
        }
    }
})
```

I need more precise look at restTemplate at his converters, but for now you can write this part this way:

```
val mapper = ObjectMapper()

restTemplate.exchange(
        URI.create("http://localhost:8080/foo"),
        HttpMethod.PUT,
        HttpEntity(mapper.writeValueAsString(Order("HELLO")), HttpHeaders().apply {
            setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        }),
        Order::class.java
).addCallback(object : ListenableFutureCallback<ResponseEntity<Order>> {
    override fun onSuccess(result: ResponseEntity<Order>) {
        println("Result: ${result.body}")
    }

    override fun onFailure(ex: Throwable) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
        if (ex is HttpStatusCodeException) {
            println(ex.responseBodyAsString)
        }
    }
})
```

As you see, i don't use KotlinModule and this code works perfectly, so obviously problem in cofiguration AsyncRestTemplate itself.

Comment: There are my playground https://github.com/IRus/kotlin-meetup/tree/stackoverflow/async-netty

Comment: Very interesting! I followed the code step by step and I can see how it is properly converted using the Mapping Jackson Converter and then flushed downstream. I suppose this flushing is probably not working as expected because when I send the payload as a string and it uses the StringMessageConverter everything works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents. This is surely not the solution.

I configured the `asyncRestTemplate` with a `AsyncHttpClientRequestInterceptor` and it magically worked. No explanation, period!

```
public class AsyncClientLoggingInterceptor implements AsyncClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<ClientHttpResponse> intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, AsyncClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {

        return execution.executeAsync(request, body);
    }
}
```